# Use de Moivre's theorem to obtain an expression for $\sin^6x$ as a sum of terms in the form $\cos ax$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I'm not exactly sure if I'm on the right lines but I've started with a binomial expansion:

$(\cos x+i\sin x)^6=\cos 6x +i \sin 6x= \cos^6 x + i(6\cos^5x \sin x)-15\cos^4x \sin^2x-i(20\cos^3x \sin^3 x)+15 \cos^2x \sin^4x+i(6\cos x \sin^5 x)-\sin^6x$

If I rearranged this for $\sin^6x$ I'd get $\cos^kx$ terms, when the question asks for $\cos ax$

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z = e^{ix}$. $\sin x = \frac1{2i} (z-z^{-1})$ and
$$\sin^6 x = -\frac1{64} (z - z^{-1})^6 = -\frac1{64} (z^6 - 6z^4 + 15z^2 - 20 + 15 z^{-2} - 6 z^{-4} + z^{-6})$$
Now remember that $\cos ax = \frac12 (z^a + z^{-a})$ to get
$$\sin^6 x = -\frac1{32} \cos 6x + \frac3{16} \cos 4x - \frac{15}{32} \cos 2x + \frac5{16}$$

Comment: Thank you! However, on your $\sin ^6x$ line, why is it $(z+z^{-1}$$? The first line has a subtract - is this a typo?

Comment: @Jim There was a typo but it's fixed now. The result was correct nevertheless because the binomial was expanded from $(z-z^{-1})^6$.
$$\sin(x) = \frac1{2i}(e^{ix} - e^{-ix}) = \frac1{2i} (z - z^{-1})$$